# How to select key value pairs elements from a list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying get the values from the below list by calling each of the keys :

```
l=["'person': 'Male'", "'name': 'James Smith'", "'dob': 'Jul 20 1955'", "'car': 'Ford'"]
```

desired output:

```
print(l['person'])

Male
```

Comment: Are you thinking of a dict?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this to be a dictionary rather than a list.

```
l = dict([x.replace("'", '').split(': ') for x in l])
print(l['person'])

...

Male
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna use a dictionary structure intead of a list.

If you define the dictionary

```
my_dict = {"person": "Male", "Name": "james Smith"}
```

then you can use the keys to index the dictionary

If you run

```
print(my_dict('person'))
```

the output will be

```
Male
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this list of strings, you could join them with `','` and add curly braces to the end to form a single string, then `eval` it into a `dict`.

```
from ast import literal_eval

d = literal_eval(f"{{{','.join(l)}}}")

print(d['person'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is fixed and you want to convert it to dict, this might help.

```py
def convertToDict(arr):
  obj_map = {}
  for obj in arr:
    k, v = obj.split(':')
    obj_map[k.strip(" '")]=v.strip(" '")
  return obj_map

l=convertToDict(l)

print(l['person']) # Man
```